# Understanding this solution to a puzzle

Tags: c, algorithm, puzzle, primes

I was doing a puzzle in a coding competition, and I'm stuck on one question. Basically I don't understand how can someone reach this solution.  The puzzle was

Alice and Bob play the following game.  They choose a number N to play with.  The rules are as follows:

1. Bob plays first and the two players alternate.
2. In his/her turn, a player can subtract from N any prime number (including 1) less than N.  The number thus obtained is the new N.
3. The person who cannot make a move in his/her turn loses the game.

Assuming both play optimally, who wins the game?

And the given solution is

```
int main() {
  long int T, N;
  for(scanf("%ld", &T); T > 0; T--) {
    scanf("%ld", &N);
    if (N % 4 == 1) {
      printf("ALICE wins\n");
    } else {
      printf("BOB wins\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What competition? Is it still on-going? It will be highly unethical to ask how to solve problems from a competition if it is still ongoing (as it is unfair for those who actually try to solve it according to the rules - by their own)

Comment: No no, its a practice question from codechef

Comment: I am glad to hear. You should also link to the specific question.

Comment: It's probably not your phrasing, but I despise "a player can subtract from N any prime number (including 1) less than N."  1 isn't prime!

Comment: @amit http://www.codechef.com/problems/NUMGAME2

Comment: @JoshuaGreen, The phrasing is wrong. They meant, any prime number or 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's sort of a [Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) game. The player who finally faces `N = 1` loses. If `N % 4 != 1`, Bob can take 1, 2 or 3 to make the next `N ≡ 1 (mod 4)`, leaving Alice in a losing position. Otherwise, if `N ≡ 1 (mod 4)` at the start, Alice can counter Bob's move to leave a number `≡ 1 (mod 4)` for Bob again.

Comment: What to do if we dont subtract prime but the divisor of number

Comment: That's far more complicated. I don't think there is an easy way to determine from which values the beginning player can force a win with that rule, but I haven't analysed that problem deeply so far. But it sounds interesting.

Comment: Actually, @neel, scratch that, it _is_ easy. If `N` is even, the beginning player can force a win (always taking 1). From an odd `N`, the beginning player loses. If `N` is odd, each divisor is also odd, then the next player has an even (winning) number left.

Comment: @neel: On the "how can someone reach this solution" part of your question: "by working backwards", as illustrated in the answer. That is, these problems are often solved by finding a small case that is a win for one of the players, and then working backwards to see how a player can force that situation.